Received Status Code 403 When Downloading Dependencies After Updating to Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1
I recently updated my Android Studio from Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 to Iguana | 2023.2.1. After the update, I tried to build one of my projects, but I started encountering dependency resolution errors.
The error message reads:

This issue happens for most of the dependencies in my project, which were working perfectly fine before the update.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Invalidate Caches / Restart: No change.
Checked my Gradle configuration: All configurations seem correct and haven’t been changed since the update.
Cleared Gradle cache and re-synced the project: The error persists.
Here’s a snippet of my build.gradle file for reference:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.20'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }

        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://android-sdk.payfort.com" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
//        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2'
        // Google Services plugin
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://android-sdk.payfort.com" }
    }

}

ext{
    RELEASE_STORE_FILE= "keyStore/keystore.jks"
    RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD= "android"
    RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS= "key0"
    RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD= "goautopoint"
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Following is the gradle-wrapper.properties file
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME


Please post errors as text, not images.

You are getting 403 errors from your Payfort Maven repository. Since they no longer seem to exist, start by removing maven { url "https://android-sdk.payfort.com" } from your roster of repositories.
Many of your dependencies will still fail, because the dependencies themselves no longer exist. For example, the first one in your error screenshot is org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:0.10.8. That is six years old and was published on JCenter, which shut down a couple of months ago. Anko was discontinued years ago. You should have replaced it years ago. You decided not to do that — now, you will have to.
Others of your dependencies will exist but you will need to move to newer versions (e.g., ExoPlayer).
